# ArrayList Dynamic remove and add for socker client

Tags: java, array, client-server, sockets

I have one ArrayList in Java and a save the socket and one unique id.

When someone client is add in the ArrayList, the `unique id` i have **is NOT the same** with position in ArrayList.

When someone client is gone i remove the client from ArrayList put `i need to find the unique id`.

**My problem:** Is when i want to send information to the Client because the ArrayList position is not the same with unique id.

**One solution:** Is when i want to send something i create one `for` in the arraylist to check if unique id is the same and then send the information in the position in the ArrayList.

Can is make something better and faster about that,or i stuck in the for solution

Thanks :P

> Edit for add code
>
> Increase one the uniqueId,connect first time the client

```
ClientThread(Socket socket) {
        //For every client is connect uniqueId add one more
        serverUniqueID = Server.uniqueId++;
```

> Remove  client from the server

```
public static void remove(int id) {

    for (int i = 0; i < clientThreadArrayList.size(); i++) {
        ClientThread ct = clientThreadArrayList.get(i);

        if (ct.serverUniqueID == id) {
            clientThreadArrayList.remove(i);
            onlineUser--;

            return;
        }
    }
}
```

> Send the message into the 2 client

```
for(int i=0; i<Server.clientThreadArrayList.size(); i++){
    //check if is the same idUniqueServer and the idUsers
    int serverId = Server.clientThreadArrayList.get(i).serverUniqueID;

    if(idUsers[0]==serverId || idUsers[1]==serverId ){
                     ......

    }
}
```

**Sorry i forget to tell you from one client i want to send the message to other client**

Sorry

Comment: Please add your code.

Comment: @MrSmith42 i add my code and something important i forgot to write before sorry :(

Answer (score 2):

Use a Map

```
Map<Integer, ClientThread> threads = new HashMap<>();
```

Add thread to map

```
ClientThread thread = new ClientThread(socket);
threads.put(thread.serverUniqueId, thread);
```

Remove a thread

```
threads.remove(id);
```

Get a thread by id

```
theads.get(id);
```

Get threads by multiple ids

```
int[] ids = {1,2,3,4};
for (Map.Entry<Integer, ClientThread> entry : threads.entrySet()) {
    // Java 8+
    if (IntStream.of(ids).anyMatch(id -> id == entry.getKey().intValue()) {
        ClientThread thread = entry.getValue();
        // Do stuff, i.e. send message
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to find something in an unordered array, iterating over it is the fastest thing you can do. You should store the Sockets in a HashMap. You can put in the id and get the corresponding Socket in constant time.

Comment: For one thing maybe.  But to find 2 or more things in an onordered array, throw the items into a hashmap where access is O(k) instead of O(n)